# Excel: Conditional formatting on merged cells with an offset

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I am trying to use conditional formatting in my merged cells. In the screenshot I merged B3:B5.

If a Cell contains the word "Apfel", I would like to format this cell and the following 3 cells (so B3 = "Apfel" ==> B3:E3 should be green).

If I try to use the conditional formatting rule [=$B3="Apfel"] an I select my desired area [Cell that contains "Apfel" ], it works. But If I merge B3 with B4 and B5, it only works for B3:E3 and not for B3:E5.

So I am trying to work with an OFFSET, but I get an Error message.

I tried [=OFFSET($C3,0,-1)="Apfel"], but it gives me a syntax error.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select everything from b3 to e9 and then conditional formatting new rule-
=$B3="apfel" 
Try this.
```

Comment: This is what I am doing right now. But I merged Cell B3:B5, so there is no B4 and B5 anymore. So if I use this rule, it only changes the color of C3, D3 and E3, but not C4, D4, E4, C5, D5 and D6

Comment: @nikeiar222
  now i see .wait because i will try

Comment: @nikeiar222
Change according with your cells =OR($B3="Apfel",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apfel",$E3)))